# How to emit events in loop using socket.io and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, socket.io, callback

I want to emit 5 events message, in a loop, using socket.io and node.js.

This is what I've tried so far:

HTML client

```
//client
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO DEMO - LOOP EMIT Events</title>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      var global_var = "";

      $(function () {
         //5 loops
          for( let i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ){
            manageEvents_v1(i)
              .then(message => {    
                console.log("call manageEvents_v1() - Promise resolved successfully - message: " + message);   
                //put received data in global variable 'global_var'
                global_var = message;
              })
              .catch(function() {
                console.log("call manageEvents_v1() - Promise is rejected");            
              });

              //use 'global_var' here, every loop, outside callback
            
          }
      });
      
      var manageEvents_v1 = function(data) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          let timer;

          socket.emit('trigger', data);
      
          function response(message) {
            resolve(message);
            clearTimeout(timer);
            socket.removeListener('feedBack_trigger', response);
          }

          socket.on('feedback_trigger', response); 

          timer = setTimeout(() => {
            reject(new Error("timeout err!"));
            socket.removeListener('feedBack_trigger', response);
          }, 10000);
      
        });
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Node.JS server:

```
//server
//////////////////
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const session = require("express-session");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

var port = process.env.PORT || 9090;

const sessionMiddleware = session({ secret: "changeit", resave: false, saveUninitialized: false });
app.use(sessionMiddleware);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

const wrap = middleware => (socket, next) => middleware(socket.request, {}, next);
io.use(wrap(sessionMiddleware));
io.use(wrap(passport.initialize())); 
io.use(wrap(passport.session()));


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  var socketId = socket.id;
    var clientIp = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;

  console.log("DEBUG - A user connected!");
    console.log("DEBUG - clientIp: " + clientIp + " || socketId: " + socketId);

  socket.on('trigger', function (data) {  
    console.log("\n ----------  BEGIN::EVENT -> trigger  -------------------- \n");
    console.log("DEBUG -> Data RECEIVED from CLIENT: " + data);
    console.log("DEBUG -> SEND back data to CLIENT: " + data);
    socket.emit('feedback_trigger', "hello from server - this is your data: " + data); // Send data to client
  });
});

////////// server listen //////////////////////////////////////////////////
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on *:${port}`);
});
```

On server console, I've got follow debug messages:

```
 ----------  BEGIN::EVENT -> trigger  --------------------

DEBUG -> Data RECEIVED from CLIENT: 1
DEBUG -> SEND back data to CLIENT: 1

 ----------  BEGIN::EVENT -> trigger  --------------------

DEBUG -> Data RECEIVED from CLIENT: 2
DEBUG -> SEND back data to CLIENT: 2

 ----------  BEGIN::EVENT -> trigger  --------------------

DEBUG -> Data RECEIVED from CLIENT: 3
DEBUG -> SEND back data to CLIENT: 3

 ----------  BEGIN::EVENT -> trigger  --------------------

DEBUG -> Data RECEIVED from CLIENT: 4
DEBUG -> SEND back data to CLIENT: 4

 ----------  BEGIN::EVENT -> trigger  --------------------

DEBUG -> Data RECEIVED from CLIENT: 5
DEBUG -> SEND back data to CLIENT: 5
```

As you can see, server messages are good, but on client side, I've received something like that:
[image]

I don't know why, but all 5 responses are with first value '1'...I can't received all values from 1 to 5.

I expected from server something like this, after every emit event from server to see a message with right value and at the end in browser console, after all 5 loops are over, to display:

```
call manageEvents_v1() - Promise resolved successfully - message: hello from server - this is your data: 1
call manageEvents_v1() - Promise resolved successfully - message: hello from server - this is your data: 2
call manageEvents_v1() - Promise resolved successfully - message: hello from server - this is your data: 3
call manageEvents_v1() - Promise resolved successfully - message: hello from server - this is your data: 4
call manageEvents_v1() - Promise resolved successfully - message: hello from server - this is your data: 5
```

After that I need those values outside Promise callback to assign them to another global variable (global_var)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but didn't help me.  As you see in my demo, I've also used Promise(), .then / .catch() clause and a timer for timeout rejected error....